# Browser locale in japanese

Tags: java, internet-explorer, firefox, localization, resourcebundle

I am testing my web application and encountered an issue with japanese set as browser locale. Firefox has 'ja' as japanese locale while IE has both 'ja' and 'ja-JP' as locales for japanese. I want to know the difference between both locales - ja & ja-JP .

Issue I am facing now is - My web application loads .properties file based on the browser locale. It loads japanese properties file (Resources_ja_JP.properties) only when the browser locale is ja_JP. I want to know whether I can load ja_JP.properties file if the browser locale is 'ja'. If both are different, can someone point the difference between two?

Comment: As already explained by @VGR, it's due to region information.
However, if the properties are independent of the region, you can modify the accepted language to be language dependent only.
In java, you can use something like `locale.getLanguage()` to get the language part. (`ja-JP -> ja`). Similarly, you can append region part too as per your usage.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot get Resources_ja_JP.properties to load if the locale is "ja".  However, you can name your file Resources_ja.properties, which *will* be loaded for both the "ja" and "ja-JP" locales.

The second part of the locale name is, as you probably guessed, the country or region.  I'm not familiar with all the places in the world where Japanese is spoken, so I'll use some Latin languages as examples:  "en-US" is United States English, while "en-UK" is British English.  "pt-PT" is European Portuguese, while "pt-BR" is Brazilian Portuguese.  A locale with one part, like "en" or "pt", is a locale which is not specific to any country or region.

ResourceBundle looks for a ResourceBundle properties file (or class) which matches the locale exactly, but if no match is found, it removes the last segment of the locale name and tries again, repeating the process until the root resource file (for locale "") is reached.